# Read from STDIN unless it's empty

Tags: c

I need to make a program in c that reads and parses STDIN. Here's my problem : I already manage several cases of error in the STDIN (wrong format etc...) but if nothing is provided, the program keeps listening for user input. I want it to throw an error such as "Nothing to read" instead. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're under a UNIX-like operating system, you can use [`select()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) to wait a predetermined time for input and, if not, just carry on.

It's very handy for waiting on inputs from any of a substantial number of different file descriptors but can just as easily be used for standard input alone if you wish.

Alternatively, you can look into the terminal functions if you're sure it's coming from a terminal, using `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()` to place the terminal in non-canonical mode and set a timeout:

```
#include <termios.h>
struct termios tio;
tcgetattr(fd, &tio);             // Get current
tio.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;          // Non-canonical
tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 50;            // Five second timeout
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tio);    // Set new
```

Standard (ISO) C, unfortunately, has neither of those as mandated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, as phrased, does not make sense. If input comes from something pipe-like, it is impossible to know how long until more input arrives. (and writing to the other end will *fail* until there is a reader, though often the parent process would still count as a reader even though it doesn't actually attempt to read).

However, if you only want to prevent hanging when input is *interactive*, just use `isatty(3)` and don't read in that case.

Comment: So if I'm supposed to read from a piped input but nothing was piped, I have no choice but to throw that useless infinite prompt ?

Comment: @KiJéy if the write side of a pipe calls `close`, the `read` will return `0`.